# Is there a boolean option to turn off point display for line charts in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

In chart.js is there an boolean option to turn off the point rendering in line charts?

[Looking through the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) there's an option for `pointRadius` and if we set that to zero, then the point disappears, and so that is one way to do it.  Just curious if there's something like a `showPoint:boolean` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `pointStyle` to `false`

```js
 datasets: [
      {
        ...
        pointStyle: false,
```

Check out the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vj3p3p?file=index.ts%3AL41)

A little bit information from [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/elements.html#point-styles)